# Make an Inline Keyboard Button in Telegram Bot, directing to a URL C#

Tags: c#, api, button, telegram, telegram-bot

I haven't worked with Inline Keyboard buttons yet, I'd like to achieve that instead of sending a link to click on, I want to make an Inline Keyboard Button, that when the user presses the button it should automatically direct him to the URL given.

Comment: That's not a question

Comment: This is a question asked by many Telegram bot developers, as you can see this was viewed enough times in the past 2 years, and has 5 votes, and should only be evaluated by Telegram developers.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that this is what needed:

```
    InlineKeyboardButton urlButton = new InlineKeyboardButton();
        urlButton.Text = "Go URL";
        urlButton.Url = "https://google.com";
```